# How to use R to convert a list of names into an equation for Dredge

Tags: r, mumin

I want to automate turning lists of names into regression equations for use in the Dredge command from the MuMIn package.

Making this:

```
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

into this:

```
globalmodel <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species, data = iris,na.action = "na.fail")
```

Theoretically, seems simple--bunch of paste0. All I need is a way to automate the 'find-replace' of turning " " into +.

Why this madness? I keep adding variables/columns to my data table, and then needing to alter the dredge equation. Also, doing this would provide me with a dredge snippet that I could cross-apply to many different future dredges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reformulate` to construct the formula

```
reformulate(names(iris)[-1], names(iris)[1])
#Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species
```

and use it in `lm`

```
lm(reformulate(names(iris)[-1],names(iris)[1]),data = iris, na.action = "na.fail")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste` and it should be faster

```
lm(paste0(names(iris)[1], " ~ ", paste(names(iris)[-1],
      collapse= "+ ")), data = iris, na.action = "na.fail")
```